# How do I perform an 'if' statement within a nested sass map (SCSS)?

Tags: css, if-statement, sass, each

As I'm new to sass (SCSS) it would appear that my ambition currently outstrips my abilities. Could someone assist me with the following task.

---

### BACKGROUND

We currently have an icon system with two distinct file formats; one is a PNG and the other an SVG. Some of our icons have BOTH file types, some have either PNG or SVG. I would like to be able to list them out separately.

Here is my SCSS variable map.

```
$image-path: "http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/img/icons";
$icons-map: (
    tick: (
        filename:       icons_tick,
        has-png:            true,
        has-svg:            false,
    ),          
    secure: (
        filename:       icons_secure,
        has-png:            true,
        has-svg:            true,
    ),
    checkout: (
        filename:       icons_checkout,
        has-png:            false,
        has-svg:            true,
    ),
);
```

And how I am *trying* to list them out...

```
/* Standard (PNG) Icons */
@each $icon-type, $icon-file in $icons-map {
    @if $has-png == "true" { 
        .icon-#{$icon-type}:after {
            background-image: url('#{$image-path}/png/#{$filename}.png');
        }
    }
}

/* Advanced SVG icons (progressive enhancement for newer mobiles, retina-style displays, etc) */
@media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    @each $icon-type, $icon-file in $icons-map {
        @if $has-svg == "true" { 
            .icon.#{$icon-type}:after {
                background-image: url('#{$image-path}/svg/#{$filename}.svg');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Only problem is that it doesn't seem to be going to plan...any ideas where I'm going wrong with this? I assume it's how I'm looping over the nested map, or how I'm setting my 'if' statement.

I would have *expected* the output to be something like this;

```
/* Standard (PNG) Icons */
.icon.tick {
      background-image: url('http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/img/icons/png/icons_tick.png');
    }
    .icon.secure {
      background-image: url('http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/img/icons/png/icons_secure.png');
    }
/* Advanced SVG icons (progressive enhancement for newer mobiles, retina-style displays, etc) */
    @media only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
        only screen and (     -o-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2/1),
        only screen and (        min-device-pixel-ratio: 2),
        only screen and (                min-resolution: 192dpi),
        only screen and (                min-resolution: 2dppx) {
    .icon.secure {
      background-image: url('http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/img/icons/svg/icons_secure.svg');
    }
    .icon.checkout {
      background-image: url('http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/img/icons/svg/icons_checkout.svg');
    }
```

}

Keep getting the error that **$has-png** and **$has-svg is an undefined variable**.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try getting the values inside your map first using `map-get`, as the returned value (`$file` in my solution below) is a list. Heres a simplified one with the 'variables' where after the `->` it means it returns that type, and after `:` is the type you need to enter here, showing you what your variable will be representing and how you then have to use them:

```
/* @each $type->string, $file->map in $icons-map:map */
@each $type, $file in $icons-map {
    /* if get-value-with-keyname-in-map($file:map, has-png:string)->boolean; is true */
    @if map-get($file, has-png) == true { 
        .icon-#{$type}:after {
            /* print get-value-with-keyname-in-map($file:map, filename:string)->string; */
            background-image: url('#{$image-path}/png/#{map-get($file, filename)}.png');
        }
    } 
}
```

Remember you are hunting for `keys` and not variables, the only existing variables are the ones you defined which means `has-png` and `has-svg` are not variables, they are keys inside a map (in this case, the map is `$file`, the value of the key `$type` in your map `$icons-map`). Also, since you defined them as `booleans` you cannot actually compare it using `== "true"` as that implies a string, so just check if they are `== true`.

The output I got from this was:

```
.icon-tick:after {
    background-image: url("http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/img/icons/png/icons_tick.png");
}
.icon-secure:after {
    background-image: url("http://www.mywebsite.com/assets/img/icons/png/icons_secure.png");
}
```

Which seems to be what you wanted.